# Opensearch Dashboards Visualization order by sub-aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, opensearch, kibana-4, opensearch-dashboards

We are trying to build a vertical stacked bar chart in Opensearch Dashboards (2.7) and we are encountering problems when sorting it.

The graph represents, for each of the accounts of our infrastructure, the percentage of elements with the agent installed.

We want the chart to be sorted showing to the left the accounts that have a higher number of elements without the agent installed (SSMAgent:false).

The graph would therefore look like this: [Actual Opensearch Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05HCm.jpg)

- on the Y axis the percentage of elements with the agent installed (as they are stacked bars, the bar will be divided into two sections SSMAgent:true and SSMAgent:false)
- on the X axis the platform accounts.

For the moment we have built the chart with the Y-axis as Metric, the X-axis as Terms (AliasAccount) and we have added a split series of filters (SSMAgent:true and SSMAgent:False).

However, when it comes time to sort, we can't find any way to make the X-axis sortable by the results of the split series filters.

Is there any way to get it sorted like this?

Thank you very much for your help